# discord.js api request command

Tags: discord, discord.js

```html
const config = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/config.json`)
var ee = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/embed.json`)
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`);

module.exports = {
    //definition
    name: "glifestats", //the name of the command 
    category: "⌨️ Programming", //the category this will be listed at, for the help cmd
    aliases: [""], //every parameter can be an alias
    cooldown: 4, //this will set it to a 4 second cooldown
    usage: "glifestats <id>", //this is for the help command for EACH cmd
    description: "check stats", //the description of the command
};

  run: async (client, message, args, cmduser, text, prefix) => {
    await interaction.deferReply();
        const term = interaction.options.getString('term');
        const query = new URLSearchParams({ term });
      const { list } = await fetch(`https://api.gtaliferp.fr:8443/v1/extinction/profiles/main/${query}`)
        .then(response => response.json());
  }
```

When i try to do this command, it does nothing.

It needs to get the query from the user message and post it to the url, example:

.command 4443

bot returns the *https://api.gtaliferp.fr:8443/v1/extinction/profiles/main/4443* data and postes it.

And also, i wanted to make the different data on an embed like this: data 1: data data 2: data .... but i cant do it, ( check the url provided for the data titles if you want to help with that)

Comment: Please indicated if the answer below fixed you question or not

Answer (score 0):

So you seperated your module from the rest of the command with this line marked below

```js
module.exports = {
    //definition
    name: "glifestats", //the name of the command 
    category: "⌨️ Programming", //the category this will be listed at, for the help cmd
    aliases: [""], //every parameter can be an alias
    cooldown: 4, //this will set it to a 4 second cooldown
    usage: "glifestats <id>", //this is for the help command for EACH cmd
    description: "check stats", //the description of the command
} //here
```

Also term is reqesting an option that is not defined

```js
const term = interaction.options.getString('term');
```

Interaction is not defined

```js
    run: async (client, message, args, cmduser, text, prefix) => { 
        await interaction.deferReply();
        const term = interaction.options.getString('term');
```

Try this

```js
const config = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/config.json`) // is this needed if not, delete
var ee = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/embed.json`) // is this needed if not, delete
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require(`discord.js`); // is this needed if not, delete

module.exports = {
    name: "glifestats", //the name of the command 
    category: "⌨️ Programming", //the category this will be listed at, for the help cmd
    aliases: [""], //every parameter can be an alias
    cooldown: 4, //this will set it to a 4 second cooldown
    usage: "glifestats <id>", //this is for the help command for EACH cmd
    description: "check stats", //the description of the command
    options: [{
        name: "term",
        description: "Code to search",
        required: true,
        type: "STRING",
    }],

    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        await interaction.deferReply();
        const term = interaction.options.getString('term');
        const url = `https://api.gtaliferp.fr:8443/v1/extinction/profiles/main/${term}`

        const list = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json())

        // Do something with list
        console.log(list)

        return interaction.followUp({
            content: `List has been logged but can't be sent yet because it is an object and need to be further worked to get specific elements from it`
        })

        // Above seemed cleaner to me


        /*
        const query = new URLSearchParams({
            term
        });
        const {
            list
        } = await fetch(`https://api.gtaliferp.fr:8443/v1/extinction/profiles/main/${query}`)
            .then(response => response.json());
        */
    }
}
```